# Image within a WPF application displays smaller than when viewed in external viewer

Tags: wpf, image, sizing

When I display a JPEG in my WPF application (using the following code), it is shown significantly smaller than if I open the JPEG in the Windows Picture Viewer at actual size.

I've drilled into the properties of my ImageSource at runtime and my image has:

- a DPI of 219
- a Height of 238.02739726027397
- a Width of 312.54794520547944
- a PixelHeight of 543
- and a PixelWidth of 713

When I use a screen ruler to measure the WPF display of the image, I get approx. 313x240 pixels (which if I could positiont the ruler perfectly would probably be equal to the Width and Height that the ImageSource is reporting.).

My gut tells me this has something to do with WPF's use of device independent units (instead of pixels) but I can't make sense of it, and I still need to know how to display the image at the 'actual' size of 543x713 in my application.

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <Image Source="Image15.jpg" Stretch="None" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a DPI of 96. WPF is scaling your image based on the size in inches, while the image viewer is displaying pixels. On most Windows systems, the screen resolution is assumed to be 96 DPI, so using that in your image will result in a one-to-one translation.

Comment: If somebody needs a tool for the DPI correction: You can use [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net), which is free and easy to use for this purpose.

Answer (score 11):

Thanks Mark! I did some Googling based on your info and found [this article](http://genesisconduit.wordpress.com/2008/07/05/wpf-images-and-dpi-independence/) that provided a solution to get the result I wanted. This is starting to make sense now...

**Edit: Linkrot. Pasting the critical text from the article here for reference....**

```
<Image Source=”{Binding …}”
       Stretch=”Uniform”
       Width=”{Binding Source.PixelWidth,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}”
       Height=”{Binding Source.PixelHeight,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}” />
```

> Here we’ve set Stretch to Uniform and bound the Width and Height to the PixelWidth and >PixelHeight of the Source, effectively ignoring DPI. The image however will not be pixel >perfect, even when using SnapToDevicePixels (which simply snaps the borders, not pixels >within the image). However, WPF in 3.5 SP1 will support a NearestNeighbor >BitmapScalingMode, which should correct this.

Comment: Used these in a MultiBinding to store in the Image control's Tag for later use, thx!

Comment: The **BitmapScalingMode** you can apply like this:
`<Image ... RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" />`

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you could extend Image and implement MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride to change the effect of the image's DPI:

```
class DpiAgnosticImage : Image
{
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        var bitmapImage = Source as BitmapImage;

        var desiredSize = bitmapImage == null 
            ? base.MeasureOverride(constraint) 
            : new Size(bitmapImage.PixelWidth, bitmapImage.PixelHeight);

        var dpiScale = MiscUtil.GetDpiScale(this);
        desiredSize = new Size(desiredSize.Width / dpiScale.Width, desiredSize.Height / dpiScale.Height);

        desiredSize = ImageUtilities.ConstrainWithoutDistorting(desiredSize, constraint);

        if (UseLayoutRounding)
        {
            desiredSize.Width = Math.Round(desiredSize.Width);
            desiredSize.Height= Math.Round(desiredSize.Height);
        }

        return desiredSize;
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        return new Size(Math.Round(DesiredSize.Width), Math.Round(DesiredSize.Height));
    }
}
```

Use it in xaml as if it were an Image:

```
<Grid>
  <local:DpiAgnosticImage
    Stretch="None"
    Source="{Binding ViewImage}">
    <Image.RenderTransform>
      <ScaleTransform
        x:Name="SomeName"/>
    </Image.RenderTransform>
  </local:DpiAgnosticImage>
</Grid>
```

Flaws to above code (that I know of):

- Ignores Stretch
- Assumes Source is a BitmapImage

=== Edit - Will's comment suggests he would like to know what is in GetDpiScale()

```
    public static Size GetDpiScale(Visual visual)
    {
        var source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(visual);

        var dpiScale = new Size(
            source.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.M11,
            source.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.M22);

        return dpiScale;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the result of the .jpg file itself specifying the DPI - WPF is simply obeying.  [Here is a forum post](https://web.archive.org/web/20120209034244/http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/db40ff3e-e30b-4cb4-8ed3-12041178abf5/) detailing the problem with some solutions: